# Go IRIS http frameowrk, I can't get routing right

Tags: http, nginx, go, server, go-iris

Ok, so first of let me start off by saying I know that with go I should really go for the net/http framework unless I have the knowledge to write my own or I explicitly tried that and it didn't work. However, I'm an idiot, and I thought I could save some time and headache by using a framework and I thought choosing one maintained by only 1 guy is a good idea. The framework is here:
https://github.com/kataras/iris
But I don't expect you to read through all of it. However, it is based on top of fasthttp which some of you might have experience with (hopefully).

The problem I'v meet with this framework is with configuration of static content serving. For example, I have my index page being served:

```
iris.Get("/", serveHome)
```

which serves and html template over at ip:port.

I have static ressources listed as such:

```
iris.Static("/css", "./client/css")
```

Which basically serves the dir css over at ip:port/css

However, when I put this all up on a server and redirected mydomain.example and www.mydomain.example to ip:port using nginx (with an ssl&tls cert), this worked:

```
iris.Get("/", serveHome)
```

and served the index.html at mydomain.example. This didn't:

```
iris.Static("/css", "./client/css")
```

And now my website can't access any static resources, because its trying to access mydomain.example/css, which, for some reason, isn't pointing to ip:port/css.

Any clue why this might be happening, have you seen this behavior on any other http server before and if so do you have any pointers that might help me figure out this thing ? I'm at a loss and any advice, even if its just speculation, would be useful.

Comment: The best advice would be: Do not use iris. The earlier you switch the better.

Comment: Unless there's something very malicious in there I'd rather stick with it for the project. Moving to net/http might take a while, but, in the end. I might do just that. It would tale 1-2 hours but I've already wasted almost 1 hour on trying various ways to solve this thing.

Comment: I don't recommend you use iris, first there's no reason to use frameworks in Go and second and more important the author has been stolen code from httprouter: https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/issues/148  Instead I recommend you this reading: https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/build-web-framework-golang/

Comment: Well, I'd like to say that a) I didn't know, there's no need to downvote me for using a frameowrk that was stolen, that's a bit overkill. b) thank you for informing me, more people should know about this, maybe github could even take some action against the iris project hosted there if its blatently stolen and infringing on a copy-left license. c) I've started swtiching to net/http already, after looking at the problem more closely it will probably take much less than I expected.

Comment: [Further Reading](http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html)

Comment: Can you show where you start listening for connections in iris? Also, have you tried using it without nginx?

Comment: @George I mean how are you calling the `Run()` function to start listening to incoming connections

Answer (score 0):

I know you're already porting this, but if i have to guess, i'd say the problem is the relative path you're using for `./client/css`.

If you're compiling this and running it form your development environment, this pretty much will run under `$GOPATH/bin` and i guess your CSS files are in `$GOPATH/src/path/to/project/client/css`... then when the compiled server tries to find `./client/css` from `$GOPATH/bin`... well, i guess you got it, it looks up in `$GOPATH/bin/client/css`. But that's just a guess, i'd need more info from your project to debug that.

Good luck with porting your project!

Comment: Ahm, I very very very very much doubt that. As far as I know a go application uses the directory you run from to run. As in, if my binary is in /path/to/dir/binary and I run ./binary, the binary will have /path/to/dir as its current directory. $GOPATH and $GOROOT are needed for the go tools and its good to have your projects sorted like that since then you always know where you binaries/sources/packages are, but on the server on which I run this I don't even have go installed.

Comment: You're right, my bad, it was just a guess. Just checked that.